# Sound card doesn't support midi. How can I play midi output in real-time?

Tags: sound, soundcard, midi

My sound card doesn't support midi, but I want to write music in TuxGuitar and listen to the midi output on the fly. Is there some program I can install to do this?

Right now my workaround is to export the files to .MID, then convert them to .MP3 using this command:

```
timidity "$file" -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k "${file[@]/%.mid/.mp3}"
```

Comment: Does `timidity -Os something.mid` (or `-Od`) work?

Comment: Oh, it does actually! There's a little crackling when it starts playing, but sounds fine otherwise. I guess the problem with TuxGuitar output is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `-iA` option, [Timidity runs as a daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/timidity#Daemon) to output the data in real time to the sound card.

Comment: I ran `timidity -iA` and changed the output MIDI port in TuxGuitar, but it's still silent.

Comment: Just checked timidity on the system monitor and it's run as `/usr/bin/timidity -Os -iAD`. So it's already running as an ALSA daemon, no?

Comment: So then you would have *two* Timidity ports?

Comment: Yeah, two ports, 128 and 129.

Comment: TuxGuitar is outputting midi now, oddly enough! I tried a few other things, but I'm 90% sure this answer fixed the issue.